# Como contar quantidade de likes de uma página?

Tags: facebook

Tenho uma página www.exemplo.com.br, lá eu embedei vários posts do Facebook. E cada post tem uma quantidade certa de likes.

Gostaria de saber, se tem como eu criar uma div, que mostre o total de likes de todos os posts contidos nessa página. Se existe alguma forma para fazer isso.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A resposta já fornecida pelo @mgibsonbr está perfeita, mas eu gostaria de compartilhar outra solução (um pouco mais complexa, é verdade) que eu utilizei no final do ano passado para obter os likes de uma série de fotos em uma campanha de uma empresa aqui de São Paulo.

Antes de tudo, eu gostaria de mencionar que quando eu desenvolvi esse código eu aprendi que não são todos os recursos (fotos, posts, etc) que podem ser livremente acessados. Algumas vezes (dependendo da configuração de privacidade do recurso) é necessário obter e utilizar o tal ['token de acesso'](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/), e para isso a página em que o código é executado precisa ser cadastrada na [Central de Aplicações do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com) para que o usuário (logado) possa conceder permissão para acesso. O exemplo que eu preparei para responder à questão não precisaria disso, mas para talvez ajudar alguém que precise eu resolvi incluir como eu fiz o processo.

O primeiro passo é acessar a Central de Aplicações (apps) do Facebook e criar uma nova aplicação. Neste momento, basta definir um nome e uma categoria (pode-se utilizar também um namespace, caso vc tenha mais aplicações sobre um mesmo domínio, digamos) para listagem da sua aplicação/página pelo FB. Vide a imagem a seguir em que eu criei a aplicação 'Teste' de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao criar uma nova aplicação, o Facebook provê um código único chamado App ID (veja imagem abaixo, no meu caso). Essa App ID é necessária para inicializar a API no Javascript e permitir ao usuário aprovar o acesso à aplicação aos dados de sua conta (só lembrando que a criação de um app não é necessário para responder à questão colocada, só estou compartilhando por achar que pode ser útil).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, basta indicar na página "*Settings*" qual é a URL em que a aplicação, página está hospedada. É possível criar diferentes tipos de plataformas (note o botão "+Add Platform") por meio das quais a sua aplicação será acessada. Neste exemplo, estou criando apenas uma **Web Page** (pois a intenção é apenas construir uma página que acessará conteúdo do FB). Para fazer o teste local, você precisa necessariamente de um servidor local (creio que não é possível fazer acesso direto ao sistema de arquivos). Eu utilizo o [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). A imagem a seguir exemplifica essa configuração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma vez com essa configuração pronta, basta criar a página e o código Javascript para acessar os dados com a permissão do usuário.

No arquivo HTML você deve colocar algum código para fazer a inicialização. O exemplo que eu preparei é apresentado a seguir. A div com id='fb-root' é requisitada pelo FB, e a definição da função em 'window.fbAsyncInit' serve para fazer a inicialização da aplicação e o login automatizado (lá há uma nota dizendo que isso não é necessário para esse exemplo, e por isso essa função pode ser comentada para acesso a recursos públicos, como neste caso). O código seguinte nesse mesmo pedaço de script executa o carregamento assíncrono da biblioteca javascript do FB (que poderia também ser carregada síncronamente, mas [essa é a forma indicada pelo Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)).

```html
<html>

      <head>
        <title>Teste de Likes</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="facebook.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>

        <!--
            Inicialização assíncrona da biblioteca javascript para o Facebook
            (conforme documentação: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart),
            com login automático e obtenção do token de acesso.
        -->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>

            /** Armazena o token de acesso */
            var gsAccessToken = "";

            /**
             * Função de inicialização e login no Facebook.
             * NOTA: Essa função é apenas necessária para acesso a recursos com privacidade controlada
             * (que requer o uso do token de acesso).
             * Para ESTE teste (com o post do Porta dos Fundos), essa função pode ser simplesmente
             * comentada (ou removida) que a consulta funciona da mesma forma.
             */
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

                // Inicio da biblioteca do FB (com definição do ID da página Web)
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '1401642456751870', // ID da página Web criada no App Center
                    status     : true,
                    xfbml      : true
                });

                // Requisição ao usuário do login no FB
                FB.login(function(oResponse) {
                    if(oResponse.authResponse) {
                        gsAccessToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                        console.log('Token de acesso = '+ gsAccessToken);
                        FB.api('/me', function(oResponse) {
                          console.log('Bem-vindo, ' + oResponse.name + '!');
                        });
                    }
                    else
                        console.log('O usuário cancelou o login ou não autorizou completamente.');
                }, {scope: ''});
            };
            // FIM DA FUNÇÃO DE INICIALIZAÇÃO E LOGIN (que pode ser comentada se desejado)

            /*
             * Carregamento assíncrono do arquivo js com a api do FB
             * (note o uso de 'pt_BR' na URL, para janelas de login/permissão localizadas).
             */
            (function(d, s, id){
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <!-- Função de callback para exibição do total de likes. -->
        <script>
            function displayLikes(iLikes) {
                alert("Total de likes do post: " + iLikes);
            }
        </script>

        <!--
            Testa com o post da seguinte página do grupo "Porta dos Fundos":
            https://www.facebook.com/PortaDosFundos/posts/643579779013746
            O ID é facilmente obtido da própria URL acima.
        -->
        <button onclick="queryLikes('643579779013746', displayLikes);">Consulta likes do post 'Careca' (Porta dos Fundos)</button>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Assim que essa página é carregada, a biblioteca do FB é carregada. Então, a função de inicialização e login é executada e uma autorização de acesso para a aplicação é solicitada ao usuário, conforme ilustra a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão incluído no corpo do HTML anteriormente apresentado executa a chamada da função 'queryLikes' passando como parâmetro um ID que é o ID do recurso para o qual se deseja obter as curtidas (likes). No meu exemplo eu usei como recurso [o post do vídeo 'Careca' do grupo "Porta dos Fundos"](https://www.facebook.com/PortaDosFundos/posts/643579779013746). O ID pode ser obtido de diversas formas, seja diretamente do link do recurso (no exemplo, para o post de URL https://www.facebook.com/PortaDosFundos/posts/643579779013746 o ID é 643579779013746) ou por consultas na [ferramenta Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/) do Facebook.

O código Javascript para a consulta dos likes que eu preparei de exemplo é apresentado a seguir:

```js
/**
 * Função de consulta dos Likes de um recurso (páginas, fotos, vídeos, etc) do Facebook.
 * @param sResourceID Identificador do Facebook para o recurso. O identificador é facilmente
 * obtido a partir de uma consulta com o link do recurso na ferramenta Graph API Explorer do Facebook.
 * @param oCallback Função de callback com a assinatura function(iLikes) a ser chamada com o resultado
 * da consulta.
 */

function queryLikes(sResourceID, oCallback) {

    var oCounter = { likes: 0 };

    // Consulta o número de likes do recurso
    FB.api("/" + sResourceID + "/likes?limit=5000",
        function(oResponse) {
            outputLikers(oResponse.data);
            queryResponse(oCounter, oResponse.data.length, oResponse.paging.next, oCallback);
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Função recursiva para contagem acumulada dos likes em múltiplas páginas.
 * @param oCounter Objeto para manter a contagem dos likes entre as chamadas.
 * @param iLikes Número de likes da atualização da paginação atual recebida do Facebook.
 * @param sNext String com o link para a próxima paginação ou null se não existir mais paginações.
 * @param oCallback Função de callback com a assinatura function(iLikes) a ser chamada com o resultado
 * da consulta.
 */
function queryResponse(oCounter, iLikes, sNext, oCallback) {
    oCounter.likes += iLikes;

    if(sNext != null) {
        FB.api(sNext,
            function(oResponse) {
                outputLikers(oResponse.data);
                queryResponse(oCounter, oResponse.data.length, oResponse.paging.next, oCallback);
            }
        );
    }
    else
        oCallback(oCounter.likes);
}

/**
 * Função utilitária para 'imprimir' no console os nomes (e IDs) dos usuários que curtiram
 * o recurso.
 * @param aData Array com os objetos de usuários que curtiram o recurso, conforme retornado pela
 * query ao FB.
 */
function outputLikers(aData) {
    for(var i = 0; i < aData.length; ++i) {
        var oUser = aData[i];
        console.log(oUser.name + "(" + oUser.id + ")");
    }
}
```

Esse código usa a API do Facebook para fazer as requisições Ajax diretamente, mas escondendo os detalhes da formação das cláusulas FQL (Facebook Query Language). Assim como na resposta anterior, o resultado é um JSON, só que nesse caso com os IDs e nomes de cada pessoa que curtiu o recurso. Como esse número pode ser bastante grande, os dados são retornados em várias páginas, e por isso o código é preparado para processar as páginas seguintes. No exemplo eu listo também os nomes e ids das pessoas que curtiram (no sistema que eu fiz no ano passado, eu criei e salvei uma listagem com nomes, IDs e emails para a empresa usar em campanhas futuras - o email você acessa em novas consultas diretamente aos ids de cada usuário - se o usuário forneceu um email público).

Vale lembrar que para fazer essa query num post de uma página de visibilidade geral como o do grupo Porta dos Fundos, você não precisa de token de acesso.

O resultado da execução desse teste é exemplificado pelas imagens a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só por curiosidade, você pode testar as chamadas da API via a ferramenta Graph Explorer, como ilustra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E, se você selecionar "FQL Query" ao invés de "Graph API", você pode testar queries tal qual fornecida pela ótima resposta do @mgibsonbr. :)

Comment: +1 por causa do passo-a-passo com imagens.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, sua dica foi fundamental, obrigado por postar detalhadamente, um abraço!

Comment: @FelipeStoker Puxa, por nada. Fico mesmo muito feliz em ter ajudado. :)

Answer (score 15):

Segundo um comentário [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896103/520779) no SOEN, é possível obter o número de likes no formato JSON através da seguinte requisição:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select like_count from link_stat where url="http://www.exemplo.com.br/post1"
```

O resultado será um JSON, com um formato do tipo:

```javascript
{
   "data": [
      {
         "like_count": 50
      }
   ]
}
```

Aqui está [a documentação do FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/), em inglês. Creio que, a princípio, você pode via JavaScript fazer uma requisição Ajax desse tipo para cada um dos posts e, quando completas, somar os resultados e mostrar na sua `div`.

**Obs.:** se preferir obter esses dados em XML, por qualquer motivo, pode usar a mesma URL proposta na resposta original:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select like_count from link_stat where url="http://www.exemplo.com.br/post1"
```

Comment: +1 Funciona mesmo. Fiz uma consulta [pelo google.com.br](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22http://www.google.com.br/%22) e o resultado foi `"like_count": 128666`.

Answer (score 4):

Você também pode usar a Graph API direto como no exemplo abaixo:

Para uma URL
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://pt.stackoverflow.com

```
{
   "id": "http://pt.stackoverflow.com",
   "shares": 1446
}
```

Para duas ou mais é só separar por vírgula e trocar ID por IDS
http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://pt.stackoverflow.com,http://google.com

```
{
   "http://pt.stackoverflow.com": {
      "id": "http://pt.stackoverflow.com",
      "shares": 1446
   },
   "http://google.com": {
      "id": "http://google.com",
      "shares": 8346103,
      "comments": 133555
   }
}
```