# Capturar dados de usuários do Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Estou tentando coletar com JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY alguns dados de usuários específicos dos quais não fazem parte da minha lista de amigos. Gostaria de capturar [**dados**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user) como: `likes`, `friends`, `posts` e `groups`.

Fiz alguns testes e não vi diferença em estar ou não logado no Facebook. O resultado quase sempre se dá por *JSON* vazio:

```
{
    data: [ ]
}
```

Em alguns casos retorna o dado correto, mas a maioria se aplica no caso de vazio.

Um caso em específico acontece com `friends`:

```
{
    error: {
        message: "Unsupported operation",
        type: "FacebookApiException",
        code: 100
    }
}
```

Os testes são feitos via a url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/{edges}?access_token={access_token}
```

Onde:

`{user-id}` = id do usuário (O meu é 100002309392122);

`{edges}` = dados que quero coletar ditos no início da pergunta e que se encontram listados na [documentação do facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user).

`{access_token}` = é a chave de acesso que a API precisa para pegar os dados.

O *token* de acesso foi gerado por mim via uma aplicação que criei apenas para gerar o mesmo. Concatenando o ID da aplicação com o caractere pipe e depois com o *App Secret* gerei o *token*.

Queria mudar esse cenário de "*JSON* vazio". Estou fazendo algo errado? Não tem como pegar esses dados? #Comofaz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma pequena confusão com o token de acesso.

Este access_token é gerado quando o usuário autoriza explicitamente a sua aplicação a acessar os dados solicitados.

Para pegar os dados do usuário é necessário que ele acessa a página em questão e autorize a app. Eu faço assim:

```
/*Esta função verifica se o usuário está logado no facebook. 
Se não estiver ele abre a janelinha de login*/
    function initFacebook() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status !== fbConnected) {
          loginFacebook(); 
        }
      });  
    }

/*Esta função vai recuperar tudo que você solicitou do usuário.*/
function carregarInformacoes() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === fbConnected) {
      FB.api('/me', {}, function(response) {
        /*Response tem tudo que você solicitou, inclusive o access_token.*/
      });
    } else if (response.status === fbNotAuthorized) {
      loginFacebook(); 
    } else {
      loginFacebook();          
    }
  });  
}

/*Esta função pede permissão de acesso aos dados. Ela que no fim das contas vai gerar o access_token*/
function loginFacebook() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      initFacebook();
    }       
  }, {scope: 'email, user_photos, friends_about_me, read_friendlists, user_education_history, user_groups, user_interests, user_likes, friends_likes, user_work_history, user_online_presence' });
}
```

Note que em carregarInformacoes eu uso o path /me. Isto é feito dessa forma para pegar os dados do usuário corrente. Uma vez autorizado você pode guardar o access_token num banco de dados da vida.

Depois disso você pode utilizar a abordagem que você está tentando.

Comment: É isso ai. :) Essa [outra questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2214/73) tem alguns exemplos de como consultar likes.