# Como verificar o número de usuários que aceitaram um evento no facebook usando o Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde ele deverá mostrar a quantidade de pessoas que confirmaram presença em um evento existente no facebook. Segundo a documentação do Graph API, para que eu possa verificar esse dado eu devo utilizar o seguinte código:

```
function getConfirm(a){
  FB.api(
    '/'+a,
    {access_token:'meu token de acesso'},
    function (i) {
      console.log(i.attending_count);
    }
  );
}
```

onde `a` é o ID do evento que eu irei buscar essa informação. O problema é que quando eu tento trazer os dados não consigo retornar nenhuma quantidade de usuários, e esse tipo de informação até onde sei é liberada para busca pois no próprio evento (através da página do mesmo) eu consigo fazer o download dos dados dele em um arquivo para calendário com todas as pessoas que confirmaram.
Alguém sabe onde está o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu li na [documentação](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event/attending), o modo correto de utilizar seria com o `/a/attending`, onde `a` é o `{event-id}`.
Isso te retornará uma lista de objetos `User`, para saber o número de pessoas, basta contar o número de objetos.

Comment: Excelente Felipe, não sabia que essas informações de estatísticas tinham sido separadas como funciona hoje com a capa do evento. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do @FelipeAvelar está correta, faltou incluir o `attending` no final da query.

De todas as formas, eu preparei um exemplo com [base nessa minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2230/73). Lá tem informações adicionais importantes (que eu propositalmente evitarei de repetir aqui) sobre como criar a sua aplicação no Facebook e como simular a página localmente.

Os arquivos HTML e Javascript abaixo ilustram uma solução para contar (e listar) os usuários que indicaram participação num evento público (ou do seu perfil, já que você tem o *access token*). Pra ilustrar, eu usei o evento do [SBGames 2014](https://www.facebook.com/events/648697541847684/).

### Arquivo HTML

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Teste de Participantes</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="facebook.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--
        Inicialização assíncrona da biblioteca javascript para o Facebook
        (conforme documentação: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart),
        com login automático e obtenção do token de acesso.
    -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>

        /** Armazena o token de acesso */
        var gsAccessToken = "";

        /**
         * Função de inicialização e login no Facebook.
         * NOTA: Essa função é apenas necessária para acesso a recursos com privacidade controlada
         * (que requer o uso do token de acesso).
         * Para ESTE teste (com o evento público), essa função pode ser simplesmente
         * comentada (ou removida) que a consulta funciona da mesma forma.
         */
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

            // Inicio da biblioteca do FB (com definição do ID da página Web)
            FB.init({
                appId      : '1401642456751870', // ID da página Web criada no App Center
                status     : true,
                xfbml      : true
            });

            // Requisição ao usuário do login no FB
            FB.login(function(oResponse) {
                if(oResponse.authResponse) {
                    gsAccessToken = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                    console.log('Token de acesso = '+ gsAccessToken);
                    FB.api('/me', function(oResponse) {
                      console.log('Bem-vindo, ' + oResponse.name + '!');
                    });
                }
                else
                    console.log('O usuário cancelou o login ou não autorizou completamente.');
            }, {scope: ''});
        };
        // FIM DA FUNÇÃO DE INICIALIZAÇÃO E LOGIN (que pode ser comentada se desejado)

        /*
         * Carregamento assíncrono do arquivo js com a api do FB
         * (note o uso de 'pt_BR' na URL, para janelas de login/permissão localizadas).
         */
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!-- Função de callback para exibição do total de likes. -->
    <script>
        function displayParticipants(iParticipants) {
            alert("Participantes no Evento: " + iParticipants);
        }
    </script>

    <!--
        Testa com o evento do SBGames 2014:
        https://www.facebook.com/events/648697541847684/
        O ID é facilmente obtido da própria URL acima.
    -->
    <button onclick="queryParticipants('648697541847684', displayParticipants);">Consulta Participantes do SBGames 2014</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

### Arquivo Javascript

```
/**
 * Função de consulta dos participantes de um evento do Facebook.
 * @param sResourceID Identificador do Facebook para o evento.
 * @param oCallback Função de callback com a assinatura function(iParticipants) a ser chamada com o resultado
 * da consulta.
 */

function queryParticipants(sResourceID, oCallback) {

    var oCounter = { participants: 0 };

    // Consulta o número de participantes do evento
    FB.api("/" + sResourceID + "/attending",
        function(oResponse) {
            console.log(oResponse);
            outputParticipants(oResponse.data);
            queryResponse(oCounter, oResponse.data.length, oResponse.paging.next, oCallback);
        }
    );
}

/**
 * Função recursiva para contagem acumulada dos participoantes em múltiplas páginas.
 * @param oCounter Objeto para manter a contagem dos participantes entre as chamadas.
 * @param iParticipants Número de participantes da atualização da paginação atual recebida do Facebook.
 * @param sNext String com o link para a próxima paginação ou null se não existir mais paginações.
 * @param oCallback Função de callback com a assinatura function(iParticipants) a ser chamada com o resultado
 * da consulta.
 */
function queryResponse(oCounter, iParticipants, sNext, oCallback) {
    oCounter.participants += iParticipants;

    if(sNext != null) {
        FB.api(sNext,
            function(oResponse) {
                outputParticipants(oResponse.data);
                queryResponse(oCounter, oResponse.data.length, oResponse.paging.next, oCallback);
            }
        );
    }
    else
        oCallback(oCounter.participants);
}

/**
 * Função utilitária para 'imprimir' no console os nomes (e IDs) dos participantes do evento.
 * @param aData Array com os objetos de usuários que indicaram participação no evento.
 */
function outputParticipants(aData) {
    for(var i = 0; i < aData.length; ++i) {
        var oUser = aData[i];
        console.log(oUser.name + "(" + oUser.id + ")");
    }
}
```

### Resultado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]