# Lista de amigos do facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Boas pessoal estou com o seguinte problema ao tentar buscar a lista de amigos do facebook da pessoa logada tenho o script feito so que so faz login nao me esta a listar os amigos da pessoa logada

Agradecia ajuda

Script

```
    <div id="result_friends"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
    function sortMethod(a, b) {
        var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
        var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: '<?= $sApplicationId ?>', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        function updateButton(response) {
            var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

            if (response.authResponse) { // in case if we are logged in
                var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    userInfo.innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
                    button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
                });

                // get friends
                FB.api('/me/friends?limit=<?= $iLimit ?>', function(response) {
                    var result_holder = document.getElementById('result_friends');
                    var friend_data = response.data.sort(sortMethod);

                    var results = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
                        results += '<div><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + friend_data[i].id + '/picture">' + friend_data[i].name + '</div>';
                    }

                    // and display them at our holder element
                    result_holder.innerHTML = '<h2>Result list of your friends:</h2>' + results;
                });

                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.logout(function(response) {
                        window.location.reload();
                    });
                };
            } else { // otherwise - dispay login button
                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    }, {scope:'email'});
                }
            }
        }

        // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    </script>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow César. O modelo da nossa comunidade é diferente de fóruns, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor. Se possível, inclua mais detalhes sobre o que está acontecendo e o que já tentou para resolver o problema. Por exemplo, o retorno está mostrando alguma mensagem (algum erro)? Criar um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pode facilitar (quem for responder sua dúvida) a encontrar o problema.

Comment: já tentei colocar na scope users_friends para ter permissao a aceder aos amigos mas nao resolvi ele faz login para quando vai para listar os amigos nao aparece nada. nao apresenta nenhum erro

Comment: Olá. Você verificou no console do navegador se está ocorrendo algum erro? A sua função de resposta à requisição dos amigos está sendo chamada? Você testou a query na ferramenta de desenvolvimento pra saber se ela está correta? Sem um erro mais específico, fica muito difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar. Dá uma olhada [nesta outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2230/73) que eu mesmo postei. Ela é sobre uma necessidade levemente diferente do seu, mas pode te ajudar a verificar se nenhum passo da comunicação via Javascript foi esquecido.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a [documentação do Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends), os únicos amigos que serão retornados serão aqueles que usam o app. Do contrário, a lista virá vazia mesmo.

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a partir da versão 2.0 da api a listagem de amigos só é mostrada se o seu app estiver na categoria jogos.