# Sincronizar álbum de fotos do facebook em site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

Em um projeto de um web site um cliente perguntou para mim se é possível ele cadastrar suas fotos no facebook e as mesmas serem atualizadas/sincronizadas em seu site, pois como trabalham com eventos, seria muito mais prático para eles.

Alguém já fez isso, ou algo parecido?

Comment: No passado eu já fiz uma página que "resgatava" duas imagens de um álbum específico no Facebook (para uma campanha de uma empresa). O código que eu postei [nesta resposta (para contagem de likes)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2230/73) foi adatapdo do que eu usei. Basicamente, se você tiver o ID do álbum onde o seu cliente postar as imagens (e ele for público!), é só fazer a consulta e processar o JSON da resposta.

Comment: Olha só, se você acessar o [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/), você pode usar queries para consultar a lista de albums de uma página pública (por exemplo: `PortaDosFundos/albums`) e a lista de fotos em um álbum (por exemplo: `310722019024363/photos` - o ID do album foi obtido na consulta do exemplo anterior).

Comment: Tenta este tutorial `http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/mostrar-albums-facebook-webs.html` pra mim deu certo!

Comment: Agradecido pelas respostas até o momento. OBS: Foi útil a resposta que antes havia. Minha sorte que copiei o link, senão teria perdido a mesma.